# Database table design for several similar columns related to those tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, phpmyadmin, database-schema, database-table

I am working on a project which has several similar forms in terms of values they are supposed to pass to database. In each form 4 out of 5 inputs and the values they hold are just same but 5th one are always different. Therefore I do not think creating several different tables for each different column is the most optimized way  and  I'd  to know the best way of  building tables  for this kind of situation.

I demonstrate forms and inputs down below.

- ***register***(name,surname,email,phone number,**training_name**)
- ***we can contact you***(name,surname,email,phone number,**training you are interested**)
- ***ask us***(name,surname,email,phone number,**your question**)
- ***become a teacher***(name,surname,email,phone number,**CV**)

As you see 5th inputs are always different for each form.

Answer (score 1):

Add a fifth table 'users' and reference this from your other tables:

- **register**(user_id,training_name)
- **we_can_contact_you**(user_id,training you are interested)
- **ask_us**(user_id,your question)
- **become_a_teacher**(user_id,CV)
- **users**(id,name,surname,email,phone)

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST A FREE DEMO(name, mobile, email, city, pincode, interested product)